# Need help in issuing the tail command to the remote server from the GUI

Tags: java, ftp, tail

I am developing a tool to collect the logs from the remote server(Solaris) to the local system(Windows). I successfully established a connection with the server using TelnetToClient.java. I tried to issue the command through Runtime.getRuntime.Exec(), but it was not working. Then I tried with the following code to send the command to the server to delete a file(Just to confirm that this way of issuing the command is working).

```
Public void exeComm(String comm){
try{
_executor.sendCommand(comm);
}catch(IOException e){
e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

Where comm is the command issued which is “rm /test” which successfully deletes the file test,located in the root directory. I followed the same way to issue the command to tail the log. Command was “`tail –f /usr/log/tracelog.log >> tailedtracelog`” but this is not issuing the command to the server and hence I am not able to tail the log which is my major requirement. I tried same delete command using Runtime.getRuntime.Exec() which is also not working. Can someone please help me on this?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hang on a sec.  So is your requirement to copy logs over from the Solaris box to your Windows box?  Or is it create some sort of a console that tails the remote log?

Comment: Hi Martijn, I am developing a tool(GUI) in windows which has to collect logs from Solaris box.

Comment: Are these logs generated by log4j or some other generic logging system?

Answer (score 1):

Ah this old classic :).  Please read [Why Runtime exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html)

Comment: I have read that article., What is the alternative way for this then?

Comment: There's a section in the article about having to split the input and output streams when dealing with remote file system commands that pipe output.